# Append element only when "content/text" is found

Tags: jquery, text, append, element

Is it possible, with jquery, to do the following:

Given a document marked up with h1 through h6, append a "back to top" link after every heading element only if there is text written after the heading and before the next..

So:

```
<h1>h1</h1>
<p>text</p>
<h2>h2</h2>
<h3>h3</h3>
text text
<h4>h4</h4>
<br><br>
<h5>h5</h5>
<br><br>text
<h6>h6</h6>
<div>test</div>
```

Would result in

```
<h1>h1</h1>
<p>text</p>
<a..>back to top</a>
<h2>h2</h2>
<h3>h3</h3>
text text
<a..>back to top</a>
<h4>h4</h4>
<br><br>
<h5>h5</h5>
<br><br>text
<a..>back to top</a>
<h6>h6</h6>
<div>test</div>
<a..>back to top</a>
```

So text can be in paragraphs, divs, spans, or not marked up at all...

I'm not sure how to do this, and how to even select the last element before the next  (or what if it's the last ?) to append the link to.

Any help (doesn't have to be a complete solution) is welcome.

**Edit: 
The biggest issue is this:**

Unfortunately I'm working with a cms that doesn't output paragraphs, but instead outputs

```
 <h1>..</h1><br>text<br><br><h2>h2</h2>
```

and so on..

So also:

```
<h1>test</h1>
<br>
<h2>test</h2>
```

using the second solution presented here, that adds a top link when it shouldn't.. I'm not sure how to prevent that.

**Edit 2:**

Tried changing to:

```
$('#content').find('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each( function(i, item) {
    var nextItems = $(item).nextUntil('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');

    if (nextItems.filter('p, div, span').size() > 0 || nextItems.filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
    }).size() > 0) {
        nextItems.last().after('<p><a href="#toc-top" class="toc-top">Back To Top</a></p>');
    }
});
```

but it's never finding text nodes.. Any reason why? contents is just the h2 followed by br and text...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6").next('p,div,span').after('<a>To Top</a>');
```

Quickest I could come up with. Won't work if text is not in a container. If you can wrap a container around the text before inserting it will be easy.

```
$('yourcontainer').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() != "") {
        $(this).after('<a>To Top</a>');
    }
});
```

*EDIT*

I think that the other answers provided are nice might work but I see a pattern in your output and hence providing you with this simple suggestion:
`$("h1,h2,h3").next('br').next('br').next('br').after('<a>To top</a>');`

Assumption: Your pattern is `(<htag>htag</htag><br>if(text){<br>text<br>})*`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add a container around this, I am limited by the CMS.. :( Is there no way around that?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy enough, provided that you enclose the text after your 
heading tags with a container:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each( function(i, item) {
        if ( $(item).nextUntil('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').text() ) {
            $(item)
                .nextUntil('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').last()
                .after('<a href="#top">Back To Top</a>');
        }
    });

});
```

This works regardless of how many nodes you have after your headings, provided that the text is wrapped in a tag of some sort.

**Update** If you can't wrap text nodes with another tag, my suggestion is to use jQuery to do this first - this will allow us to process the code consistently, and work around the limitation of `nextUntil`. Update my code above to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // wrap text nodes with a span
    $('#container') // note that I'm using a container reference to scope this - adjust as needed 
      .contents()
      .filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
      }).wrap('<span class="temp" />');

    $('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each( function(i, item) {
        var items = $(item).nextUntil('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
        if ( items.text().match(/[^\s]/gi) ) {
            // Only insert a back to top link if these nodes contain at least one non-whitespace character
            items.last()
                .after('<a href="#top">Back To Top</a>');
        }
    });

    $('#container').find('span.temp').replaceWith(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    });

});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THvM2/1/)

Comment: Thank you, this comes very close. Unfortunately I'm working with a cms that doesn't output paragraphs, but instead outputs <h1>..</h1><br>text<br><br><h2>h2</h2> and so on.. any ideas? see original post for more info. (btw, had to remove the .text() from your code sample for this to work)

Comment: For some reason .text() just returns "" while .size() returns the correct nr of elements. Why is that?

Comment: @Wesley - see my update above for a suggestion for processing text nodes

Comment: @Dexter .. I think you should clean up the wrapper after processing is done. Also, what is the need to cache 'items' if you are not using them anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use '.contents()' method to recognize text nodes.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#content').contents()
            .filter(function () { return (this.nodeType == 3); })
            .wrap('<p class="temp"></p>');

        var headers = "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6";
        $(headers).each(function () {
            var $currentHeader = $(this);
            if ($currentHeader.is('h6')) {
                var $siblings = $currentHeader.nextAll();
                if ($siblings.text().trim()) {
                    $siblings.last().after('<a href="#">Top</a>');
                }
            }
            else {
                if ($currentHeader.nextUntil(headers).text().trim()) {
                    $currentHeader.nextAll(headers).first().before('<a href="#">Top</a>');
                }
            }
        });

        $('#content').find('.temp').replaceWith(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        });

    });
```

Basically, I'm finding all the text nodes and wrapping them in a temporary `<p>`. We then add the `<a>` elements where necessary. Once the whole processing is done, we safely remove the temporary `<p>` elements.

Jsfiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/amritayan/GXLFL/